# What is a test that I can use to determine if a time series is first-order stationary?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, mean, stationarity

I need to test that one of the time series in my analysis has a constant mean over time. Is there a standard test I can use to help me determine this?

I know that I can use a nonparametric procedure where I test for equality of means across subsamples of the original sample, but I was hoping to use an alternative procedure if possible. As far as I can tell, all of standard tests for (non)stationarity are for the second-order case (constancy of mean and variance with respect to time).

Comment: The question in your title asks about determining first-order stationarity whereas in the text of your question, you ask only about the mean being constant which covers a much wider class of time series than the first-order-stationary time series. Which property do you really want to test?

Comment: Thank you Dilip. My main interest is in testing for a constant mean.